# Apache web server won't display a webpage

Tags: centos, httpd

I've literally tried everything to get my web server broadcasted to the public but it's just not working. Every time I type my server IP in a browser like firefox it just gets stuck on "Waiting for ipaddress..." forever.

So here's what I did:

- I completely reinstalled the operating system. I am using Centos 7 & Google Cloud
- I installed httpd using the simple step by step guide as seen here:
  https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-apache-on-centos-7
- I verified that the server is listening on port 80 with the
  command:

netstat -anp | grep httpd.

```
sh-4.2# netstat -anp | grep httpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18025/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     23993    18025/httpd
```

At first it was listening on tcp6 so
I typed in the command nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and changed "Listen 80" to "Listen 0.0.0.0:80" 
I still can't connect to my web server after restarting it.

I tried configuring virtual hosts by following the guide here: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/set-up-virtual-hosts-on-centos/

I am not running IPtables.. I had no problems opening up port 80 in firewalld with the commands

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=https --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd ––reload
```

I also tried

```
sudo firewall-cmd ––permanent ––add-port=80/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd ––permanent ––add-port=443/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd ––reload
```

I then typed 
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all and saw that services http and https were listed

I still couldn't get a web page when I type the server ip in my browser so I completely **disabled selinux and firewalld**. It's still not working.

I installed IP tables and opened the necessary ports:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

In the VPC Network -> Firewall Rules tab in Google Cloud you can clearly see that http is open for all ip ranges

```
default-allow-http
Ingress
http-server
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:80
Allow
1000
default
```

I used a curl command in the SSH console to test the website
curl -I http://localhost

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 22 Dec 2019 15:19:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Sun, 22 Dec 2019 14:54:44 GMT
ETag: "5-59a4c176b0e2b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

And it responded with 200 OK.. Meaning everything was configured correctly. I opened all the ports and still cannot get a page to display when I type the server IP in my firefox browser. I don't understand.... What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: 
Here is the error log

```
[Sun Dec 22 16:11:14.246082 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 1244] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Dec 22 16:11:14.262897 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1244] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Dec 22 16:11:14.262979 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 1244] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun Dec 22 16:11:14.270177 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1244] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 22 16:11:14.270214 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1244] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to a problem on Google's end. For some reason even though port 80 and 443 was already open it wasn't actually. I had to delete default-allow-http and default-allow-https and reopen port 80 and 443 now the website is working.